# Is there any way to check power on/off of devices connected with serial port (RS-232)?

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port

I have two devices connected with serial ports (RS-232). When they are on, I don't have any problem with controlling the devices but when they are off, my software, when it's writing to the device, is not responding at all.

Is there any general way to programmatically check the devices are on? Or do I need to contact each manufacturer on this? Simply checking port connection didn't work because the port to a powered-off device can be opened without any problem.

Thanks and happy new year guys.

Comment: I never programmed a device with serial, but if a device is off, it is as if there was nothing connected ? Ie, no electricitcy in the pins. Maybe you can check this.

Comment: If it doesn't respond, it's probably off.

Comment: @Synxis Exactly. But I am not sure I can find a way to do that.

Comment: By "serial" do you mean "RS-232"?  Because USB is also serial, and it has enumeration capability.  Ditto SATA, SAS, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, serial ports don't provide any mechanism to know if the other device is connected or powered.  In your app, you can send a request and then timeout awaiting response to determine the other side is down.

Comment: It depends on what protocol they are using and how it is wired. You have the DSR(dataset ready) and the RTS/CTS hand shaking signals. You can allways check the state of those pins.

Comment: RS-232 DOES provide such a mechanism (having a small voltage between RX and GND is forbidden), but few implementations pass this information through to software.

Comment: @MarkHall, but checking the state of flow control pins is completely unreliable if the other side is powered off and not driving the pins.  You would be sensing a floating input, which is totally arbitrary.

Comment: @TJD If it is hooked up most likely would still have a load, if disconnected you are right

Comment: The load is at the receiver end, i.e. yours.  Just because there is no driver does not mean that the lines are floating.

Comment: @BenVoigt, your receiver may or may not have pull ups.  If not, then the inputs are floating.